# Opening file through a pipe

Tags: c++, file, io

I'm trying to write a program that allows me to type something like this on the command line:

```
cat inputfile | myprogram outputfile
```

In myprogram I need to open both the input and output file without the input file being a parameter. I know how to open the output file and set it to a descriptor:

```
int out=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
```

But I don't know how to do this with the input file. I know the output of cat is sent to the cin of my program but I don't want to read the file in line by line. Is it possible to do this in a way similar to opening the output file? Like so:

```
int in=open(?????,O_RDONLY);
```

Comment: `std::cin` is just another `std::istream` -- while line-by-line processing is common, it's not mandatory. You can read a character at a time, or use block-reads to process large chunks at a time.

Comment: I know about those but is there any way to make them stop reading once there is no text left to read? They make me specify a length to read to and end up adding garbage data to the end. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: They don't add any garbage to the end -- they just read to the end, and don't overwrite anything after that. You can initialize the buffer beforehand (e.g., to all 0's) or you can use `gcount` to find how much data you got in the last read.

Comment: I must be initializing the buffer wrong because I still get garbage at the end. Im writing buffer[65536]={}. Is there a better way to do it? Likewise, the buffer always ends up being the size 65336 when the file I input is only around 40000. This is an issue because when I write the buffer to a new file, the file also ends up being of size 65536.

Comment: UPDATE: gcount solved my problem, I was doing it wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In C it can be solved like

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int flags=fcntl(0,F_GETFL);
        fcntl(0,F_SETFL,flags|O_NONBLOCK);
        char ch;
        while(read(0,&ch,1))
        {
                printf("%c",ch);
        }
}
```